# Is there any possibility in swagger2 to create a centralized swagger document for two different spring boot projects?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I have two spring boot projects namely A and B. Now, I need to create a centralised swagger document for both A and B projects. Any ways to do it other than with maven multi-modules?

Thanks in advance